# What is the meaning of the configuration item "balance" in the TDengine's configuration file taos.cfg?

Tags: database, tdengine

What is the meaning of the configuration item "balance" in the TDengine's configuration file taos.cfg?
Can TDengine balance data replicas in the cluster automatically？
Can TDengine balance leader membership in the cluster automatically？such as leader membership transfer in Raft?

Comment: load balancing is controlled by parameter “balance”, which determines to turn on/off automatic load balancing. Src: https://www.taosdata.com/en/documentation/architecture

Answer (score 0):

"balance" is a parameter in configuration file which determine whether TDengine cluster should automatically start load balance when meet three situation:

1. When a new data node is added to the cluster, the system will automatically trigger load balancing, and the data on some nodes will be automatically migrated to the new data node without any manual intervention.
2. When a data node is removed from the cluster, the system will automatically migrate the data on the data node to other data nodes without any manual intervention.
3. If a data node is overheated (too large amount of data), the system will automatically load balance and migrate some vnodes of the data node to other nodes.